# Boundary Check Error

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, device

Recently, I made some changes to an iOS app. Nothing special, but it was an app originally written for iOS 2.x, and now I had to go through the Xcode 4.x & iOS 5 hoopla. I survived. At least, that is what I thought.

As a result of the whole operation, my app now runs on ANY iOS device, EXCEPT the second generation iPod touch with iOS 4.2.1. (the original version ran fine on any device).

The puzzling (at least to me) part is the following:

- The App runs fine in the debugger. Also after quitting the app, I can just start it, and it will run fine
- If I however make an (ad hoc) archive of the app, save it as an .ipa, and send it to the iPod through iTunes sync, the app starts up, but crashes after a while. The app downloaded from the AppStore behave exactly like that.

I would LOVE to find out what's going wrong here, but the issue doesn't occur during debugging.

I have removed the legacy Entitlements.plist, but also played around having the Entitlements.plist around. It didn't make a difference. (As you might read between the lines, I feel a bit insecure about this part, because I don't really understand the Entitlements.plist, nor have I ever understood it.)

Also, I made sure, that both on Project and Target level, the iOS Deployment Target is set to 3.2, which is well below the iPod's OS version. The Base SDK is set to "Latest iOS".

Finally, I triple-checked that Xcode was up to date.

More than 300.000 people have downloaded my app. According to Flurry, 6.6% have this fatal combination of hard- and software. In the last Version Information in the AppStore, I put out a warning for this issue, but I'd have rather solved it. That is first priority. Understanding the problem would be second.

Please help!

Here is the Device Crash Log (I'm not too familiar with this, so I might post too much):

```
Incident Identifier: 12DED19E-8BF2-4BE0-A578-4778498D6BE7
CrashReporter Key:   2040f536aa51a5eb273f2d57dd42f748032a4419
Hardware Model:      iPod2,1
Process:         MyApp [1858]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/C240F91A-3440-418A-8C6E-C7E6BD75761B/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-03-04 22:53:37.585 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32d25ad0 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32d25abe kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32d25ab2 raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32d3cd5e abort + 54
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3582fa00 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 588
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x301888d8 _objc_terminate + 160
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3582d100 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3582d178 std::terminate() + 16
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3582d2a0 __cxa_throw + 100
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30186f28 objc_exception_throw + 104
10  CoreFoundation                  0x35e9670e -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 150
11  MyApp                           0x00004932 -[RootViewController setInfo] (RootViewController.m:195)
12  MyApp                           0x0000437c -[RootViewController toggleView] (RootViewController.m:90)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x35eada3c -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 20
14  UIKit                           0x3384af18 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 128
15  UIKit                           0x3384ae80 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 32
16  UIKit                           0x3384ae48 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
17  UIKit                           0x3384aa98 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 528
18  UIKit                           0x3384b5c4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 452
19  UIKit                           0x3383cea8 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 580
20  UIKit                           0x3383c4dc -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 388
21  UIKit                           0x3381fc94 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 444
22  UIKit                           0x3381f3ac _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6816
23  GraphicsServices                0x35262c80 PurpleEventCallback + 1040
24  CoreFoundation                  0x35e9a5c4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 22
25  CoreFoundation                  0x35e9a582 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 158
26  CoreFoundation                  0x35e8c82e __CFRunLoopRun + 574
27  CoreFoundation                  0x35e8c504 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
28  CoreFoundation                  0x35e8c412 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
29  GraphicsServices                0x35261d1c GSEventRunModal + 188
30  UIKit                           0x33865574 -[UIApplication _run] + 580
31  UIKit                           0x33862550 UIApplicationMain + 964
32  MyApp                           0x00002ba2 main (main.m:13)
33  MyApp                           0x00002b6c 0x1000 + 7020
```

And here is the SetInfo:

```
- (void) setInfo {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger  theFrame = [defaults integerForKey:@"currentFrame"]; 
    MyAppAppDelegate * myDelegate = (MyAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSMutableArray * currentCartoons = [myDelegate invert:[myDelegate readPreferences]];
    MyAppcartoon * thisCartoon = [currentCartoons objectAtIndex:theFrame];

    //format publication & date
    NSArray * titlePreSeparator = [thisCartoon.title componentsSeparatedByString:@"("];
    if ([titlePreSeparator count]>1) {
        NSString * titleSuffix = [titlePreSeparator objectAtIndex:1];
        NSArray * titleSeparator = [titleSuffix componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
        NSString * pub = [titleSeparator objectAtIndex:0];
        flipsideViewController.Publication.text = pub;




    } else {// in case the publication metadata is missing from the rss
        flipsideViewController.Publication.text = @"";
    }

    //format title
    NSString * titlePrefix = [titlePreSeparator objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray * titleFixer = [titlePrefix componentsSeparatedByString:@"F&S "];
    flipsideViewController.Title.text = [titleFixer objectAtIndex:1];

    //format date
    flipsideViewController.Date.text = [self formatDatefromrss:thisCartoon.publicationDate];

}
```

Comment: Please post the crash reports found in the device logs in the XCode organizer.

Comment: @NJones : I have included the log in the original question. Hope it gives a clue

Comment: Can your post your `setInfo` method of the RootViewController class? Its the method where your app crashes when accessing an array, presumably with an index that is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not surprised this code had trouble. There is very little bounds checking in it at all. Though the `objectAtIndex:` that stands out to me is:

```
flipsideViewController.Title.text = [titleFixer objectAtIndex:1];
```

It wouldn't surprise me if this was line 195 in your source code.

Comment: You are absolutely right. My bad. I found out that this is a problem that is actually repro on all devices and all OS's;
I will open a new question for the real problem. I hope you will be around again.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the crash log definately shows that your app crashes in the `setInfo` method of your RootViewController class (you can see that in the stack trace, the `[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]` is called from the `setInfo` method). Your `setInfo` method has two array access that isn't secured. `[titleFixer objectAtIndex:1];` and `[titlePreSeparator objectAtIndex:0]`, pretty much at the bottom of the method.

Comment: Thanks! I had to reward NJOnes, because he was first.